# I was solving a story where there is a puzzle of the following

Tags: cipher, pattern

I was solving a story where there is a puzzle of the following... Can anyone help?

There was the picture of Rod of Asclepius beside the alphabets, if this is any sort of clue.

[image: Puzzle]

[image]

What can fit inside that ? mark?

Comment: I can't make head or tails of the text, but the numbers on the bottom row seem to be the factorial of the sum of the numbers in the top row, which would make the ? (2 + 2)! = 4! = 1·2·3·4 = 24.

Comment: ya it is true i think

Comment: If you include the story, that might be helpful...